# Model and instance classes separation

Tags: c#

Should you ever separate a class into different parts, assuming there will be common values inside of it or are there some reasons against it?

For example:

```
public class Car
{
    public string ModelName { get; }
    public string Class { get; }
    public string Engine { get; }

    public Color CarColor { get; }
    public uint Mileage { get; }
    public uint IssueYear { get; }
}
```

could be separated into:

```
public class CarModel
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Class { get; }
    public string Engine { get; }
}


public class CarInstance
{
    private CarModel _car_model;
    public string ModelName { get => _car_model.Name; }
    public string Class { get => _car_model.Class; }
    public string Engine { get => _car_model.Engine; }

    public Color CarColor { get; }
    public uint Mileage { get; }
    public uint IssueYear { get; }
}
```

Comment: The instance class you created as an example is just the model class with some business logic to it. Are you asking if business logic should be kept separate from a model? If so that's a whole different question.

Comment: What do mean by instance classes? This is the first time I have heard that term.

Comment: @Logarr there isn't really any logic inside of those classes, so that's not what i meant (probably)

Comment: @brainlesscoder i don't know how else to call this thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand now what you are asking for. Well, first of all this is very broad questions and highly opinionated. But I will try to answer as briefly as possible. Since, I follow DDD (Domain Driven Design), the approach largely depends on the `Bounding Context`.

> You can read about bounding context here https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html

if your bounding context deals with only `Cars` and only what Make, Model or Year they are made of you can go with a structure like this -

```
public class CarInstance
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Class { get; }
    public string Engine { get; }
}
```

Since you will only ever use these values in conjunction of a car; not independently. In this bounding context, the details of those items are insignificant. An example of such system is - if  you are building an asset management system for a family and only ever concerned about the value of the car.

But, consider a different bounding context. Say, an insurance company, who issue insurance based on car model, make and year. For this bounding context it if very very important for you to know the model, make and year. Because based on those your insurance premium changes. Now, you need to dig deeper into the context and an example model might look like this -

```
public class CarMake
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string PriceMultiplier{ get; }
    public string PenaltyOffset{ get; }
}

public class CarModel
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string PriceMultiplier{ get; }
    public string PenaltyOffset{ get; }
    public CarMake Make { get; } //since model is dependent on Make. For example BMW models are not same as Toyota models.
}

public class CarYear
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string PriceMultiplier{ get; }
}

public class CarInstance
{
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; }
    public CarModel Model { get; }
    public CarYear Year{ get; }
}
```

As you see if vastly depends on what you are building.

**Suggestion -**

Try to understand your bounding context well. You will find out yourself what you need.

Comment: so basically do whatever as long as it makes sense in the given context? ok then...

Comment: yup. Some people try to see further ahead, say 5 years and try to make sense what could change in this time. That gives you better idea.

Answer (score 3):

In your example separation will be a good choice. You can do it by using [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance).

```
public class CarModel
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Class { get; }
    public string Engine { get; }
}

public class CarInstance : CarModel
{
    public uint Mileage { get; }
    public uint IssueYear { get; }
}
```

Comment: not what i meant... In my example multiple car instances could reference the same car model

Comment: @beothunder what useful functionality do you get out of multiple CarInstances referencing the same instance of CarModel?

Comment: @Logarr lets say you have a store with 3 toyyodas and 2 oniisans, and instead of storing some common data separately you could move it into a `CarModel ` class.

Comment: @beothunder That's now how that should be done at all. In you example you can't separate which properties are shared and which are common. Color is a property of a car, but could be different between two specific cars with the same model/engine/whatever. Would you put a color property in yet another class?

Comment: @Logarr if a property can be changed, then it should be inside the `CarInstance` class. i think...

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're looking for now. This is similar to how a `Product` and `ProductType` relationship work on an ecommerce platform. In my experience, although you could technically achieve the same thing with inheritance like isidat's answer shows, it's not an accurate representation of how the data would exist in say, a relational database.

However, the example you gave is overcomplicated. If you want your CarModel information to be readonly, then simply set the property for it in `CarInstance` as `readonly` like so:

```
public class CarModel
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Class { get; }
    public string Engine { get; }
}

public class CarInstance
{
    public readonly CarModel CarModel;
    public uint Mileage { get; }
    public uint IssueYear { get; }
}
```

The CarModel would have to be provided during construction, but that's not a problem because you shouldn't be constructing a `CarInstance` without knowing which `CarModel` it's going to be.

I would like to point out however that in reality a car tracking system would have it even more granular than you have here. `Engine` would be a class, `Class` would be a class, even `PaintJob` would be a class. Basically any element that could be reused between instances of a car would be their own classes, and their own relational tables in a database.